# Build order and dependencies not preserved on upgrade from VS 2008 to 2010 with msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, dependencies

I'm in the process of upgrading our VS 2008 solution to run on VS 2010
I managed to successfully build in VS 2010

My next step now is to configure a build machine running TFS 2008
Whenever I start a build it does my projects in alphabetical order with no regard for dependencies. I've googled a lot and I can't seem to find a solution to this.

The closest solution to my problem is found here: [msdn link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/f808e19c-2cd0-46fa-91e4-5c6444df754d) which links to this: [dependency solution](http://victorsergienko.com/project-dependencies-of-visual-studio-2008-broken-in-msbuild/)

However I'm dealing with **129** projects, so I would **really** rather not do this all manually in the xml.
Has anyone been able to effectively remap the dependencies in a way which msbuild recognizes without manipulating the xml for days...?

Comment: I'm converting a solution with 100+ projects right now, and have encountered the same problem:  MSBuild says that the C# projects aren't selected to build in the configuration.  If I discover anything, I'll be sure to let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the conversion to VS 2010 makes the build agent have to use the .NET 4.0 version of msbuild.
So I followed the steps outlined here and it worked: [Building .NET 4.0 Applications Using Team Build 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willbar/archive/2009/11/01/building-net-4-0-applications-using-team-build-2008.aspx). Keep in mind that those instructions were written during the beta and the path is now v4.0.30319.
This was required even though all my projects are targeting 3.5

Basically I had to make a one line change and now everything is happy (still working on getting my build to pass but the order is good). It had nothing to do with dependencies not being preserved, simply that the way dependencies were being managed wasn't understood by msbuild 3.5

Answer (score 0):

We also have a large number of projects.  We wound up (programmatically) creating a MasterSolution.sln file that contained all of the projects.  We also require our developers to only use project references in their code.  This way, MSBuild always gets the correct order as it parses the .sln file.